# Customize allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures to only apply to back navigation, not forward

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, webview, wkwebview

I have a simple webview in my SwiftUI iOS app. It works great but I wanted to add some navigation features so it's easier to look through the documentation page that opens up. [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414995-allowsbackforwardnavigationgestu) says I can use allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures to allow swipe gestures to go back or forward but I **just need back** not forward.

I've tried creating a DragGesture to override the default mechanism, but it didn't work properly. Should I just create my own gesture tracker and not use the property?

I'm fairly new to Swift and SwiftUI as well.

Comment: Isn't it a get-only property? How am I supposed to set it to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by just removing forward navigation in the webView itself. Here's how in jQuery and Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState('', null, './'); // Replace './' with your desired URL

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      window.history.pushState('', null, './'); // Replace './' with your desired URL
    });
  }
});
```